# Conflicts in writing/reading a file

Tags: c, multithreading, file-io, concurrency

I'm developing a little software in C that reads and writes messages in a notice-board. Every message is a .txt named with a progressive number.

The software is multithreading, with many users that can do concurrent operations.

The operations that a user can do are:

1. Read the whole notice-board (concatenation of all the .txt file contents)
2. Add a message (add a file named "id_max++.txt")
3. Remove a message. When a message is removed there will be a hole in that number (e.g, "1.txt", "2.txt", "4.txt") that will never be filled up.

Now, I'd like to know if there is some I/O problem (*) that I should manage (and how) or the OS (Unix-like) does it all by itself.

(*) such as 2 users that want to read and delete the same file

Comment: Seriously, use a database, not the filesystem. Also, your description has not convinced me that you should be using multiple threads yet.

Comment: I know with a db is all more simple, but it is not permitted in my specifications...

Comment: The most important duty of a programmer is to tell people dumber than you why the specifications are wrong.

Comment: Not if you want to pass an university exam. This exam is specific for C/Unix and it is not about DBs.

Comment: Then fail. Attempting to perform this task would be a violation of ethics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have an Unix-like, OS will take care of deleting a file while it is open by another thread : the directory entry is immediately removed, and the file itself (inode) is deleted on last close.

The only problem I can see is between the directory scan and the open of a file : race conditions could make that the file has been deleted.

IMHO you simply must considere that an error *file does not exist* is normal, and simply go to next file.

What you describe is not really bad, since it is analog to MH folders for mails, and it can be accessed by many different processes, even if locking is involved. But depending on the load and on the size of the messages, you could considere using a database. Rule of thumb (*my* opinion) :

- few concurrent accesses and big files : keep on using file system
- many accesses and small files (several ko max.) : use a database

Of course, you must use a mutex protected routine to find next number when creating a new message (credits should be attributed to @merlin2011 for noticing the problem).

You said in a comment that your specs do not allow a database. On the analogy with mail handling, you could alse use a single file (like traditionnal mail format) :

- one single file
- each message is preceded with a fixed size header saying whether it is active or deleted
- read access need not be synchronized
- write accesses **must** be synchronized

It would be a poor man's database where all synchronization is done *by hand*, but you have only one file descriptor per thread and save all open and close operations. It makes sense where there are many reads and few writes or deletes

A possible improvement would be (still like mail readers do) to build an index with the offset and status of each message. The index could be on disk or in memory depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The easier solution is to use a database like sqlite or MySQL, both of which provide transactions that you can use ot achieve consistency. If you still want to go down the route, read on.

The issue is not an IO problem, it's a concurrency problem if you do not implement proper monitors. Consider the following scenario (it is not the only problematic one, but it is one example of one).

1. User 1 reads the maximum id and stores it in a local variable.
2. Meanwhile, User 2 reads the same maximum id and stores it in a local variable also.
3. User 1 writes first, and then User 2 overwrites what User 1 just wrote, because it had the same idea of what the maximum id was.

This particular scenario can be solved by keeping the current maximum id as a variable that is initialized when the program is initialized, and protecting the get_and_increment operation with a lock. However, this is not the only problematic scenario that you will need to reason through if you go with this approach.